# How to write the logic for deleting an object and other objects associated to it using delete method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
"addCompany": [
    {
      "companyName": "HCL",
      "industryName": "s/w",
      "dateFormat": "ddmmyyyy",
      "dateFieldSeperator": "/",
      "officePremisisNo": 1005,
      "street": "Sector 62",
      "city": "Noida",
      "state": "Uttar Pradesh",
      "pincode": "201015",
      "primaryEmail": "sppd@gmail.com",
      "secondaryEmail": "spd@gmail.com",
      "primaryMobileNo": 8876543566,
      "secondaryMobileNo": 7788765445,
      "status": "active",
      "id": 1
    }
]
"addBranchToCompany": [
    {
      "branchName": "HCL Noida",
      "city": "City",
      "state": "State",
      "status": "Active",
      "contactPerson": "Miles",
      "primaryEmail": "miles@gmail.com",
      "secondaryEmail": "info@HCL.com",
      "primaryMobile": "8899876566",
      "secondaryMobile": "8876566567",
      "companyId": "1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "branchName": "HCL Ghaziabad",
      "city": "City",
      "state": "State",
      "status": "Active",
      "contactPerson": "Peter",
      "primaryEmail": "peter@gmail.com",
      "secondaryEmail": "info@HCL.com",
      "primaryMobile": "8867675665",
      "secondaryMobile": "8867565778",
      "companyId": 1,
      "id": 2
    }
]
```

Consider the above JSON. I want to know how can I delete all the branches associated to the company when I delete a company.
My requirement is that when I delete a company using delete method, all branches associated to it also gets deleted. How can I do that? Please advise.

```
deleteCompany(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    // this.companies.splice(id-1,1)
    this.repository.deleteCompany(`addCompany/${id}`).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('deleted');
      this.getCompanies();
    });

    
    this.repository.deleteBranch(`addBranchToCompany?companyId=${id}`).subscribe(()=>{
    console.log("branch deleted");
    })
  }
```

I used this logic to delete the branches associated to a company when I delete a company using delete method.
I know it will throw an error if there is no branch associated to a company and that can be handled using if condition, but my main concern is how do I solve the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
deleteCompany(id: number) {
  console.log(id);

  // First, delete the branches associated with the company


  this.repository.deleteBranch(`addBranchToCompany?companyId=${id}`)
.subscribe(
    () => {
      console.log("Branches deleted");

      // After the branches are deleted, delete the company
      this.repository.deleteCompany(`addCompany/${id}`).subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log("Company deleted");
          this.getCompanies();
        },
        (companyError) => {
          console.error("Error deleting company:", companyError);
        }
      );
    },
    (branchError) => {
      if (branchError.status === 404) {
        // Handle the case where no branches are associated with the company
        console.log("No branches associated with the company");
        this.repository.deleteCompany(`addCompany/${id}`).subscribe(
          () => {
            console.log("Company deleted");
            this.getCompanies();
          },
          (companyError) => {
            console.error("Error deleting company:", companyError);
          }
        );
      } else {
        console.error("Error deleting branches:", branchError);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I just came to know that the branches will have companyId as a foreign key in the branches table and the deletion thing will be handled in the backend. 
But still, thanks :)